# How to merge latex tables by one column

Tags: tables

Suppose I have several tables that are in this format (I will put the example data at the end)

table 1

[image]

table 2

[image]

As you can see the column `variables` is the same in both tables.

I am working in overleaf, so I have the tables (1 and 2) as tex files in a folder.

How can I merge this two tables, so I can get this:

Desired output:
[image]

Is there any function to do this? Because I have a lot of tables, and I find it clumsy to do it "by hand"

### Thanks in advance!!

Example data:
table 1

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
variables & group a & group b & diff \\ \midrule
x         & a11     & b12     & d13  \\
y         & a21     & b22     & d23  \\
z         & a31     & b32     & d33  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

table 2

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
variables & group a & group b & diff \\ \midrule
x         & c11     & f12     & g13  \\
y         & c21     & f22     & g23  \\
z         & c31     & f32     & g33  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Desired Output:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
variables & group a t2 & group b t2 & diff t2 & group a t1 & group b t1 & diff t1 \\ \midrule
x         & c11        & f12        & g13     & a11        & b12        & c13     \\
y         & c21        & f22        & g23     & a21        & b22        & c23     \\
z         & c31        & f32        & g33     & a31        & b32        & c33     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no other way than manually edit those table , especially merged tables has different column headers as have individual table. However, you  can "merge" tables (again manually), as subtables in one table.

Comment: @Zarko ): that's sad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a unix based system (e.g., Linux; maybe MacOS: I haven't tested it there), you can use the `paste` command to accomplish this.

First save the "guts" of the tables as files:

**t1.txt**

```latex
variables & group a & group b & diff \\ \midrule
x         & a11     & b12     & d13  \\
y         & a21     & b22     & d23  \\
z         & a31     & b32     & d33  \\ \bottomrule
```

**t2.txt**

```latex
variables & group a & group b & diff \\ \midrule
x         & c11     & f12     & g13  \\
y         & c21     & f22     & g23  \\
z         & c31     & f32     & g33  \\ \bottomrule
```

Now run this command in bash or zsh in the terminal:

```bash
paste -d '&' <(sed -e 's/\\.*//' -e '1s/&/t2 \&/g' \
    -e '1s/variables t2/variables/' -e '1s/$/t2 /' t2.txt) \     
    <(sed -e 's/^[^&]*&//' -e '1s/&/t1 \&/g' -e 's/\\/t1 \\/' \
    t1.txt) | column -s '&' -o '&' -t
```

The output is this:

```latex
variables & group a t2 & group b t2 & diff t2 & group a t1 & group b t1 & diff t1 \\ \midrule
x         & c11        & f12        & g13     & a11        & b12        & d13  t1 \\
y         & c21        & f22        & g23     & a21        & b22        & d23  t1 \\
z         & c31        & f32        & g33     & a31        & b32        & d33  t1 \\ \bottomrule
```

Let me break that down.

The `paste` command merges files that are arranged in the same order, line by line. The `-d '&'` tells it to use `&` as the delimiter rather than the default tab.

We want to modify the files before merging, however, so we use the `<(...)` construction in place of file names, and these will point to the output of the commands inside the parentheses.

Now consider the first one:

```bash
sed -e 's/\\.*//' -e '1s/&/t2 \&/g' -e '1s/variables t2/variables/' -e '1s/$/t2 /' t2.txt
```

The `sed` commands performs four substutitions on the file `t2.txt`. The first one `'s/\\.*//'` chops off the part from `\\` onward in each line, because we don't want to duplicate that. The next one `'1s/&/t2 \&/g'` adds "t2" before each `&` but only on the first line. Since we don't want "t2" after "variables", the third one `1s/variables t2/variables/` removes that first `t2`. Finally `'1s/$/t2 /'` adds a "t2 " at the end of the first line.

The output of this will be merged, line by line with the output of the other one.

```bash
sed -e 's/^[^&]*&//' -e '1s/&/t1 \&/g' -e '1s/\\/t1 \\/' t1.txt
```

Here there are three substitutions made to `t1.txt`. The first one `'s/^[^&]*&//'` removes everything up to and including the first `&` on each line, since we don't want to duplicate the first column which is common to both tables. The second one `'1s/&/t1 \&/g'` again adds `t1` before each `&` on the first line. And `'1s/\\/t1 \\/'` puts "t1" in the last column before the `\\`.

The output of that is already more or less what you want, but I also pipe it into:

```bash
column -s '&' -o '&' -t
```

This will add extra spaces to align all the `&`s in the output, since the addition of the `t1`s and `t2`s in the header line would otherwise make them no longer match up with the rows below.

Depending on exactly what all your tables look like, it might be easier to manually make the additions to the header rows rather than figuring out the `sed` stuff, and manually remove the duplicated columns, and just run

```
paste -d '&' t2.txt t1.txt
```

Which will just merge the contents as is line by line.

Sorry can't help you if you're using Windows (though you could probably do it with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, WSL).

Comment: Thanks!! but i use windows, I gotta do it manually ):

Comment: I'm sure there are comparable tools on Windows: just don't ask me what they are! If you know even the basics of any programming language, you could write little program to do this fairly easily too.