# Merge columns with similar rows from another table (from stargazer in r)

Tags: overleaf, r, combine

I have two descriptive statistics tables created through the stargazer package in R.

Table 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.3 by Marek Hlavac, Social Policy Institute. E-mail: marek.hlavac at gmail.com
% Date and time: Jeu, oct 20, 2022 - 19:57:12
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \label{}
 \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} \\ 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Growing season} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Violence & 83,412 & 0.090 & 0.287 \\ 
Battles & 83,412 & 0.047 & 0.212 \\ 
SocialUnrest & 83,412 & 0.070 & 0.256 \\ 
SPEIshock & 177,304 & 0.220 & 0.208 \\ 
VCIshock & 154,266 & 0.317 & 0.315 \\ 
TCIshock & 150,937 & 0.353 & 0.315 \\ 
\ \ \ {\emph{Agroecological Zones:}}\\
Tropics, highland & 178,740 & 0.423 & 0.494 \\ 
Tropics\_ lowland & 178,740 & 0.331 & 0.470 \\ 
Subtropics, warm & 178,740 & 0.425 & 0.494 \\ 
Subtropics, moderately cool & 178,740 & 0.026 & 0.159 \\ 
Subtropics, cool & 178,740 & 0.015 & 0.121 \\ 
Cold, no permafrost & 178,740 & 0.012 & 0.111 \\ 
Extreme soil conditions & 178,740 & 0.241 & 0.428 \\ 
Dominantly builtup land & 178,740 & 0.009 & 0.095 \\ 
Dominantly hydromorphic soils & 178,740 & 0.083 & 0.275 \\ 
Dominantly water & 178,740 & 0.040 & 0.197 \\ 
Desert, Arid Climate & 178,740 & 0.109 & 0.312 \\ 
     \ \ \ {\emph{Farming systems:}}\\
Perennial mixed & 178,530 & 0.015 & 0.121 \\ 
Fish based & 178,530 & 0.098 & 0.297 \\ 
Pastoral & 178,530 & 0.185 & 0.389 \\ 
Maize mixed & 178,530 & 0.256 & 0.436 \\ 
Agropastoral & 178,530 & 0.296 & 0.457 \\ 
Highland mixed & 178,530 & 0.042 & 0.200 \\ 
Arid pastoral oasis & 178,530 & 0.026 & 0.160 \\ 
Humid lowland tree crop & 178,530 & 0.050 & 0.218 \\ 
Root and tuber crop & 178,530 & 0.158 & 0.365 \\ 
Highland perennial & 178,530 & 0.039 & 0.194 \\ 
Forest based & 178,530 & 0.056 & 0.231 \\ 
Cereal root crop mixed & 178,530 & 0.138 & 0.345 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
  \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
  \small
    Notes: Each observation is a cell/year binary variable. 
 \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Table 2:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.3 by Marek Hlavac, Social Policy Institute. E-mail: marek.hlavac at gmail.com
% Date and time: Jeu, oct 20, 2022 - 20:18:57
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Non-growing season} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} \\ 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Non-growing season} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Violence & 72,660 & 0.086 & 0.281 \\ 
Battles & 72,660 & 0.045 & 0.207 \\ 
SocialUnrest & 72,660 & 0.066 & 0.248 \\ 
SPEIshock & 153,911 & 0.230 & 0.203 \\ 
VCIshock & 137,301 & 0.378 & 0.356 \\ 
TCIshock & 132,653 & 0.370 & 0.339 \\ 
\ \ \ {\emph{Agroecological Zones:}}\\
Tropics, highland & 155,700 & 0.446 & 0.497 \\ 
Tropics, lowland & 155,700 & 0.279 & 0.449 \\ 
Subtropics\_warm\_Bi & 155,700 & 0.446 & 0.497 \\ 
Subtropics, moderately cool & 155,700 & 0.018 & 0.132 \\ 
Subtropics, cool & 155,700 & 0.011 & 0.102 \\ 
Cold, no permafrost & 155,700 & 0.010 & 0.101 \\ 
Extreme soil conditions & 155,700 & 0.231 & 0.422 \\ 
Dominantly builtup land & 155,700 & 0.008 & 0.086 \\ 
Dominantly hydromorphic soils & 155,700 & 0.090 & 0.286 \\ 
Dominantly water & 155,700 & 0.034 & 0.181 \\ 
Desert, Arid Climate & 155,700 & 0.106 & 0.308 \\ 
\ \ \ {\emph{Farming systems:}}\\
Perennial mixed & 155,550 & 0.008 & 0.092 \\ 
Fish based & 155,550 & 0.073 & 0.261 \\ 
Pastoral & 155,550 & 0.190 & 0.392 \\ 
Maize mixed & 155,550 & 0.270 & 0.444 \\ 
Agropastoral & 155,550 & 0.318 & 0.466 \\ 
Highland mixed & 155,550 & 0.046 & 0.210 \\ 
Arid pastoral oasis & 155,550 & 0.026 & 0.158 \\ 
Humid lowland tree crop & 155,550 & 0.020 & 0.141 \\ 
Root and tuber crop & 155,550 & 0.157 & 0.364 \\ 
Highland perennial & 155,550 & 0.034 & 0.180 \\ 
Forest based & 155,550 & 0.047 & 0.212 \\ 
Cereal root crop mixed & 155,550 & 0.145 & 0.353 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to add the columns from Table 2 into Table 1 like in the following picture (I did it by hand).

[image]

Comment: I gave an answer to a very similar question just a couple days ago; see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662184/how-to-merge-latex-tables-by-one-column).

Comment: Thanks @frabjous. I would prefer tips via latex directly though.